# Custom jQuery validate rule is getting ignored

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 with jQuery validate() plugin. I'm trying to create a custom rule for this form element:

```
<input type="text" name="save_walklist_name" id="save_walklist_name" placeholder="Enter walklist name" value="" aria-required="true" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
```

Here's the javascript I'm using to validate this field:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {

  $.validator.addMethod('isUnique', function(value, element) {
    return false;
  }, 'Error');

  $( "#save_walklist_form" ).validate({
    rules: {
      save_walklist_name: {isUnique : true, required: true }, 
    },
  });
});
```

The required rule works fine but the custom `isUnique` rule gets ignored. I've tried various things but wihtout success.

Comment: There probably shouldn't be a commas  after `rules: {},`  and `_name: {},`

Comment: Removing the commas did not fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Cory, an extra comma ("trailing comma of death") is only a critical issue in older versions of Internet Explorer that no longer have any meaningful use.

Answer (score 0):

OK, total bonehead mistake on my part. I forgot I was automatically generating the validate code and attaching it to a `<script>` element at the end of the form. The code I was adding to the `<script>` tags at the top of the page was getting ignored.